# FreeBSD doesn't shutdown

Tags: shutdown, freebsd

I installed *FreeBSD-10.0-RELEASE-i386-dvd1* on my Vmware worksattion 10.
I can log in to it by my username but when I what to shutdown it using the statement "*shutdown -p now*", it says: "*Permission denied*". So I have to use this command: "*su*" followed by the root password (which I've given it at the installing time), but this time it says: 
"*Sorry*"
The current time and date followed by: "*BAD SU*" my username to root password "*on /dev/ttyv0*"

While I enter the root password proceeded by the *SU*, so why I can't shutdown it safely, please?

Comment: Has your password special chars (maybe keyboard encoding problem) ?

Comment: No. For example, consider it is something like _Programming_.

Comment: Is your user member of group wheel?

Comment: I don't really now. I'm novice at FreeBSD and installed it using the written instructions in the FreeBSD Handbook. I first made the root password, and a locale (or something like that- I've forgotten its correct name now) user (because it has been said that this way shutting down is more safe) by my name (here, Aria Abbasi) then a password for my user (say, _computer_). But I think there was a group named Abbasi made.

Comment: What is the output of groups yourusername?

Comment: How to be aware of that? Should I type _groups yourusername_ followed by Enter to see that?

Comment: % _groups_ _<youruser>_, if you don't see _wheel_ group, you should add it, http://www.networkinghowtos.com/howto/enable-su-access-for-users-in-freebsd/

Comment: I wrote _% groups <Abbasi>_ (which is _%_ space _groups_ space _<Abbasi>_) then pressed Enter. Got this: _Syntax error: Newline unexpected (expecting word)_.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14903/discussion-between-user1279647-and-abbasi).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not member of group *wheel*, to add a user to a this group:

```
pw user mod <username> -G wheel
```